# ¿Cómo ignorar texto que esté entre comillas con replace?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de reemplazar unos textos, lo había hecho con expresiones regulares

```js
var text = `
print("print()")
`
text = text.replace(/print\(/g, "console.log(");
new Function(text)();
```

El texto se obtiene a través de una petición a una API REST, el problema es que si uso expresiones regulares, se va a reemplazar incluso lo que esté entre comillas, cosa que no quiero

El resultado que quiero sería algo así

```
console.log("print()")
```

Pero, como la expresión regular reemplaza todo queda así

```
console.log("console.log()")
```

El código que tengo hasta ahorita es

```js
function replace(str, r) {
    if (r === str) {
        return str
            .replace("print", "console.log")
            .replace("void", "document")
            .replace("[args]", "arguments")
            .replace(":", "::")
            .replace("end", "{end}")
            .replace("fn", "abc");
    } else {
        result = str;
        r.split(" ").forEach(el => {
            result = result.replace(el, "");
        });
        return result
            .replace("print", "console.log")
            .replace("void", "document")
            .replace("[args]", "arguments")
            .replace(":", "::")
            .replace("end", "{end}")
            .replace("fn", "abc");
    }
}

function compile() {
    // fetch(this.to).then(r => r.text()).then(resp => {
    let resp = `print("print() [args] : end fn void");`
    let inString = false;
    const split = resp.split("");
    let result = resp;
    split.forEach(el => {
        if (el === '"' || el === "'" || el === "`") {
            if (inString === false) {
                inString = true;
            } else {
                inString = false;
                result = replace(result, resp);
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
};
/*}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});*/

compile();
```

Básicamente lo que hace es hacer un `split` para recorrer cada letra del string, y de encontrarse `"` o `'`, se reasigna la variable `inString` y ejecuta la función `replace` que lo que hace es reemplazar los elementos que quiero por las asociaciones del caso

Por ejemplo, si tuviera el string

```
void print("void print()");
```

Quisiera obtener

```
document console.log("void print()")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tengo poco conocimiento de expresiones regulares, pero podrías intentar esto:

1. Extraer todos los textos entre comillas y remplazarlos temporalmente con una marca o código que difícilmente podría aparecer en el texto original.
2. Aplicar todos los cambios necesarios.
3. Remplazar las marcas con los textos originales entre comillas.

```js
var text = `
print("print()");
myFunction(param) {
    print("El parámetro recibido es: " + param + " otra vez print()");
};
`;

// Crear marca que difícilmente aparecerá en texto recibido
let mark = '{{~x~}}';
// Extraer todos los textos entre comillas
let matches = text.match(/"([^\\"]|\\")*"/g);
// Remplazar cada coincidencia con la marca
matches.forEach(match => text = text.replace(match, mark));

// Aplicar los cambios necesarios al texto
text = text.replaceAll('print(', 'console.log(');
// Remplazar cada marca por el texto que corresponde
matches.forEach(match => text = text.replace(mark, match));

// Comprobar
console.log(text);
```

Seguramente habrá cosas a considerar y verificar, como que el código pueda incluir comentarios con comillas sin cerrar o el uso de comillas simples, entre muchas otras posibilidades.

Estoy seguro que hay mejores formas de lograr lo que quieres, pero esto es lo único que se me ocurrió.